# ActiveAdmin with form of association opened in default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How to turn the form auto opened without the needs of click in button?

From this button:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXOec.png

To this form:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRpAD.png

My code is like this:

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "User" do
    f.input :name
    f.has_many :addresses, allow_destroy: true  do |b|
      b.input :street
      b.input :number
      b.input :complement
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want. You want a form which can be sent without a click button, so with the enter key ?

Comment: No. When the page load, the form for association is hide and users need to click in a button to show this form, I want that the form of association is visible in default, so the users do not need to click in the button to open the form for association.

Comment: If you want to add some javascript in activeadmin, you should see here : https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/340

Comment: Did you get this to work @JonatasEduardoSalgado